# How would I make this "team only item" script work?

Tags: lua, roblox

This is one of my first times writing in Lua so I'm not very good at it. Your suggestions and corrections would mean a great deal!

This is the code that isn't working:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)

    workspace.StarterPack:WaitForChild("Script")

    game:GetService(("Teams"):GetChildren()) do

        if plr.TeamColor == ("Really blue")then
            workspace.StarterPack.Script.Cuffs.State=Enabled:("True")
end)
```

Code is in:

- Starter Pack
- (inside) script
- (inside) tool

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't compress the code in that way because it make's it pretty '*unreadable*'. Do you have got any kind of debug information which could guide us towards the main problem? Because as far as I can notice there are several non-ended blocks like the **function**, **if statement** and the **do**.

You could try to use this between. So in case you could post any source data, which you've got the inspiration from, would allow us to adapt the answer for what you are looking for:

```
local function handleConnection( thePlayer )
    workspace.StarterPack:WaitForChild( "Script" )

    if ( thePlayer.TeamColor == "Really blue" ) then
        workspace.StarterPack.Script.Cuffs.State = true
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect( handleConnection )
```